# How does a simple question get put hold for being unclear?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, questions

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277688/space-elevator-solved
I don't understand what is unclear about this question?

Comment: It's worth noting that that post is now on its 13th revision since being posted (less than 36 hours ago). Close voters may have been acting on an earlier version. The close happened between versions 9 and 10.

Comment: Any idea, why you voted to close your own question?

Comment: As of revision 24, I find this question completely incomprehensible.